# GPIOd not detecting rising edge but SYSFS implementation did

Tags: linux-kernel, gpio, device-tree, debian-buster, libgpiod

I am working to upgrade a sysfs event polling rising edge detection implementation to `gpiod` to make use of the kernel event timestamping.

In testing I found that the `gpiod` is not able to detect rising edge's on my pins for some reason. I verified this was not a usage issue by testing with `gpiomon` in command line. `gpiomon` was also not detecting rising edges, although it did detect falling edges.

I cannot figure out why the old sysfs edge detection would function normally while the `gpiod` would not.

Relevant info:

- kernel v4.19.94-ti-r73
- libgpiod v1.4.1
- TI AM33xx processor
- Debian buster OS

Device Tree is a combination of these:

- https://github.com/RobertCNelson/dtb-rebuilder/blob/4.19.x/src/arm/am33xx.dtsi
- https://github.com/RobertCNelson/dtb-rebuilder/blob/4.19.x/src/arm/am335x-osd335x-common.dtsi

and this:

```dts
&am33xx_pinmux {
    ecap0_pins_default: ecap0_pins_default {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x964, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE0) /* gpio0[7] */
        >;
    };
    gpio3_pins_default: gpio3_pins_default {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x99c, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE7) /* gpio3[17] */
        >;
    };
};
```

When I run gpiomon on one pin I get both rising and falling edges:

```sh
gpiomon gpiochip0 7
event:  RISING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072918.200972377]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072918.700979793]
event:  RISING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072919.200997043]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072919.701002002]
event:  RISING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072920.201015460]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072920.701029335]
event:  RISING EDGE offset: 7 timestamp: [1709072921.201066377]
```

But When I run it on another I get only falling edges:

```sh
gpiomon gpiochip3 17
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 17 timestamp: [1709073108.897098295]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 17 timestamp: [1709073109.897153795]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 17 timestamp: [1709073110.897172545]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 17 timestamp: [1709073111.897198629]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 17 timestamp: [1709073112.897222629]
event: FALLING EDGE offset: 17 timestamp: [1709073113.897253671]
```

Checking /sys/kernel/debug/gpio shows that they are definitely configured as IRQs:

```auto
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-31, parent: platform/44e07000.gpio, gpio-0-31:
gpio-7   (ECAP0_IN_PWM0_OUT   |gpiomon             ) in  hi IRQ
gpiochip3: GPIOs 96-127, parent: platform/481ae000.gpio, gpio-96-127:
gpio-113 (MCASP0_AHCLKR       |gpiomon             ) in  lo IRQ
```

Running a sysfs based monitor on *either* pin is able to detect both rising and falling edges.

I suspect this is either a kernel issue in my kernel version or a device tree issue, but I can't figure it out. The part that really throws me is that the sysfs based gpio event polling works fine on the same pins.

Note: I realize it would be great to update the kernel/package versions, but unless I can pinpoint exactly what is not working and what update will fix it, I cannot. They are being updated as a different development effort elsewhere with a different priority.

TL;DR:
Why is `gpiod` not detecting rising edges on some pins, but it is detecting falling edges?

Comment: Sorry if not clear, the question is why would libgpiod not detect rising edges but would detect falling edges.

Comment: With the amount of data you've included in your question, it's hard to tell. Which hardware are you using? Which pin? Which OS? You did include the version of libgpiod, so that's good. Under what conditions have you tested it? I see [tag:c++17] tag, but I don't see any C++ code. Please include more data.

Comment: As a side-note, I've successfully used [this library](https://github.com/dimitry-ishenko-cpp/gpio) in the past but it hasn't been updated in a few years.

Comment: I removed the c++ tag, because as I mentioned in the question, I found the issue presents not just in my application, but also in the libgpiod command line tools.

Comment: Try the library in my other comment. I believe it uses the same API as libgpiod with default backend. If it works, there may be a bug in libgpiod.

Comment: So I'm now finding that *some* pins work just fine (both in gpiomon and my code) but others don't, which really leads me to believe its some sort of devicetree issue, but I'm using basically the default am33xx device tree. (and at least not modifying the problem pins)

Comment: Seems unlikely to be a libgpiod issue given it works fine on other hardware. Though the event rates are very different, it is most likely either a hardware or kernel issue - libgpiod is just the middleman. Btw, libgpiod 1.4.1 is ancient - you should switch to a more recent release, ideally v2.  Not that I expect that will change anything, but no one is about to go debugging 1.4.1, and more timestamping options are available in v2.  Though that requires a kernel 5.10+ and you don't mention your kernel version.

Comment: @KentGibson Yeah eventually will be moving up, but for the next year stuck on kernel 4.19.

Comment: You have mode 7 for another pin, are you sure that mode is GPIO? I'm not. It also maybe an open source / open drain one, which you logically assume may generate interrupts only on a single edge. I believe the answer to your question is in TI AM33xx TRM and not in software.

Comment: This was followed up on and resolved in this [issue](https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/issues/59) in the **libgpiod** repo - it is a bug in pre-4.20 kernels, and lucky Dan is on 4.19.